# Unable to install openssh-server on ubuntu 16.04 in Docker

Tags: 16.04, docker, openssh

I have a Docker container with a brand new install of Ubuntu 16.04, I'm unable to install `openssh-server` successfully. I'm able to install `openssh-client` successfully but when attempting `apt-get install -y --fix-missing openssh-server` I get the following error...

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/ncurses/ncurses-term_6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1_all.deb Bad header line Bad header data [IP: 91.189.88.174 80]
```

I've tried `apt-get clean` and `apt-get update` prior to installing this. I've run out of options on googling things, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

I notice that the URL it's attempting to fetch the file from is `http://archive.ubuntu.com` instead of `us.archive.ubuntu.com` why is this?

Comment: Show us the complete output of `apt-get update`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had taken down my old docker container so I was setting up a new one to get the results and this time it installed without a hitch... considering this resolved. If it happens again I'll post more details.